# Confuse about clear float style in bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css-float

I read an article about clear float [How To Clear Floats Without Structural Markup](http://www.positioniseverything.net/easyclearing.html)

then I check the `.clearfix` in bootstrap:

```
.clearfix {
  *zoom: 1;
}

.clearfix:before,
.clearfix:after {
  display: table;
  line-height: 0;
  content: "";
}

.clearfix:after {
  clear: both;
}
```

and I find some differences, and I have several questions:

1. Why the `clearfix` separate to several parts?
2. Why the `display` is `table`, not the `block`?
3. Why this use `line-height` not the `height`?

Answer (score 5):

*Why the clearfix separate to several parts?*

**Answer:** 
Usually

```
clear: both
```

is used to clearing floats and here in bootstrap, .clearfix is a style class and as per the layaout design :before and :after selectors (which are css3 selectors) are used so technically clearing float is used only once.

*Why the display is table, not the block?*

**Answer:**

```
display: block
```

is just to show the element and not to style but display: table is used to display the element in a tablular manner.

*Why this use line-height not the height?*

**Answer:**
    line-height
is spacing between two lines while attribute "height" is used to allocate height of an element. (you can play here with

```
line-height
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mastermindw/Wuwsh/2/)

I hope these clears your doubts!